# Sum up first 4 elements of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like these: i want to sum every first 4 elements:

```
Array([0] => 0.00[1] => 26749.82[2] => 3209.98[3] => 0.00[4] => 0.00[5] => 25465.36 [6] => 3055.84[7] => 0.00[8] => 0.00[9] => 11883.00[10] => 1200.00[11] => 0.00)
```

`1 = 29958.82`

`2 = 28521.2`

`3 = 13083`

Comment: do you want to sum first 4 element in array or first 4 digits in per element?

Comment: Loop the array, add the value of the first 4, check the count then display, reset the value and count then continue for the rest

Comment: On SO, you are expected to attempt to self-solve before posting a question.  The volunteers here are meant to fix your code, not write it from scratch.  If you have a coding attempt, you should add it to your post to avoid receiving additional downvotes.  (not my downvote)

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like that :

```
array_map('array_sum', array_chunk($yourArrayToSum, 4));
```

It will return for your array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 29959.8
    [1] => 28521.2
    [2] => 13083
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop the array and sum them up.

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
foreach ( $array as $key => $value) {

    (float) $sum += $value;

    if (in_array($key, array(3,7,11)) {
        echo $sum;
    }

}
```

Or you could try this, not as clear but does the same thing.

```
$sum = 0;
$len = 11;
for ($i=1; $i<=$len; $i++) {

    (float) $sum += $array[$i][0];

    if (in_array($key, array(3,7,11)) {
        echo $sum;
    }
}
```

I've edited as per my comment i misinterpreted the question. While these will work just fine, There are other questions that are simpler to work with.

Comment: This answer does not correctly process the 12-element array.

Comment: I didn't interpret the question correctly, reading over it again, I assume now that it is a sum for array elements 0-3, 4-7 and 8-11.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_slice` to get a part of an array and build-in `array_sum` to achieve this :

```
$a = array(0.00, 0.2459, 0.688, 0.5, 10);
$b = array_slice($a, 0, 4);
echo array_sum($b); // you'll get 1.4339 in this example
```